# Couldn't connect to a CS1.6 LAN server via the internet

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike

To make it clear, I am going through each step.

Firstly, four of my friends are connected with routers and with a different ISP. They are using protocol 47, CS1.6 and Windows XP. On the other hand, I am using Windows 7 32bit, another ISP with the same protocol 47.

Now, to connect to a different ISP, we usually go to Google and type "what is my IP" and connect to that IP. As they are mutually connected with each other via router I cannot enter their network with "what is my IP". The HLDS server host also made `sv_lan 0`, but no success.

It's showing establishing network connection... Then retrying connection... Then exiting.

Any solutions please?

Comment: your OS normally doesn't affect anything. Did you try being a server and let your friends join you? Otherwise you may try some virtual LAN program(for example *Hamachi*), I used it a lot a while back. You create a password protected room there, let your friends join it and then your computers think that they are in the same LAN. *Hamachi* is seen as a separate network adapter by Windows

Comment: yeah man , they can join me in my HLDS but i cant join them. no i didnt tried hamachi ,though heard a lot about it. nyway thnx man . but any other solution using HLDS and the logic y i could not join them but they can join me on my server host using HLDS

Comment: LAN via internet makes no sense, unless you are within a VPN.  Are you trying to make a LAN server, or a private internet server?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play on a server you or one of your friends is hosting, there're 2 ways to do so.

First one is a tunnel adapter client like Hamachi, Tungle or something similiar to avoid several ports required. Such an client emulates a lan-network over the internet.

Second way is to host as you tried (with sv_lan 0) but then you've to keep in mind, that you and/or your friends connecting through the Steam assigned ports which then have to be open forwarded.

[Required Steam ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711&l=english)

To open any kind of ports you normally have to access your router and have to look for an option called "Port Forwarding". There you've to open the ports and link them to your PC's ip adress, which should be a static one (e.g. 192.168.0.1) to avoid that your PC get another ip on the next restart.

Furthermore you should whitelist Steam and Counter Strike 1.6 on all installed firewalls, even the Microsoft Firewall.
After all these steps you should be able to connect to each other.

All these steps are mostly important for the one who want to host the Server.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your friends have a firewall between their PCs and the internet. Then they need to open/forward port 27015 UDP. You have the port obviously opened ;)